# How to join a MultiValueMap with Stream api?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap extends Map<String, List<String>>` hierarchy. I want to collect all values just as a concatenated csv string:

```
        HttpHeaders headers;
        headers.entrySet().stream()
                .map((key, values) -> key + "=" + values) //TODO incompatible parameter types
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Question: how can I join the `(key, values)` pair correctly? As I get the error above.

Comment: `... + values.toString()`? that is a `List` after all

Comment: I want to control the separator myself (and maybe apply futher processing). So I don't want to use a tostring here. The question is, how can I properly access the key-value set in my first .map() method?

Comment: `.... + String.join(separator, values)` in such a case?

Comment: also this `.stream()
                .map((key, values)` looks very fishy, as `map` accepts only a single parameter as it is a `Function`.

Comment: you already _have_ an entry in the `map` step - this code does not even compile + you seem to not even explain what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Collectors.joining`

```
List<String> result = headers.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);    //[KEY2 = v1,v2,v3, KEY1 = v1,v2,v3]
```

As @Eugene suggested you can also use `String.join`

```
 List<String> result = headers.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + " = " + String.join(",",e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you don't have to stream, just to join, `String::join` would be enough

Comment: Updated will that solution also @Eugene

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing with the `values`:

```
[...]
.map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
[...]
```

**Edit:** as @Eugene said, the parameter is a Map.Entry `(e)` and not `(key,values)`

Answer (score 0):

What about joining the values with streams?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("KEY1", Arrays.asList("v1,v2,v3"));
    headers.put("KEY2", Arrays.asList("v1,v2,v3"));
    List<String> res = headers.entrySet().stream().map(stringListEntry ->
            stringListEntry.getKey() + "=" +
                    String.join(", ", stringListEntry.getValue())
                                ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(res);
}
```

result

```
[KEY2=v1,v2,v3, KEY1=v1,v2,v3]
```